# What is the significance of fine flour, oil, frankincense, and salt being essential elements in the grain offering?

Tags: leviticus, offering

Here's what I've [gathered](https://www.gotquestions.org/grain-offering.html):

- Grain offerings typically consisted of wheat or barley.
- Unlike other sacrifices, grain offerings had some flexibility.
- Could be offered uncooked or cooked in an oven or pan (Leviticus 2:1; 4-5).
- Required to be finely ground with oil and salt, without yeast or honey (Leviticus 2:1, 4, 13; 2:11).
- A portion was burnt on the altar with frankincense, the rest went to priests (Leviticus 2:10).
- No fixed amount for the offering; people gave as they could.

Leviticus 2:1,13 NKJV

> ‘When anyone offers a grain offering to the Lord, his offering shall
> **be of fine flour**. And he shall **pour oil on it**, and **put frankincense on
> it.**

> 13 And every offering of your grain offering you shall **season with
> salt**; you shall not allow the salt of the covenant of your God to be
> lacking from your grain offering. With all your offerings you shall
> offer salt.

**What is the significance of fine flour, oil, frankincense, and salt being essential elements in the grain offering?**

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding the composition and function of the offerings is actually found in 2 Sam 24:24 -

> “... I will not offer to the LORD my God burnt offerings that cost me
> nothing.”

All these ingredients of burnt offerings had the following characteristics

- all ingredients were relatively expensive, including salt, to an agrarian subsistence society that was ancient Israel
- all ingredients, despite cost, were available

Now to the particulars of the composition of these offerings:

- **Salt** - was reminder of the covenant (Lev 2:13) of salt (Num 18:19, see also 2 Chron 13:5) that Israel operated under.  That covenant was eternal (Num 25:12, 13, Ps 106:30, Jer 33:18, 21, 22) and very solemn.  Salt is a preservative and symbolized the eternal nature of the covenant.
- **Frankincense** - was to counteract (to some extent) the foul smell of the burning meat and other food in these offerings.  It also symbolized the coming messiah that these offerings symbolized and as recognized by the magi - the incense was used to signify divinity
- **olive oil** was a symbol of the Holy Spirit (Luke 4:18, Acts 10:38, 2 Cor 1:21, 22, 1 John 2:20), as was also fire (Matt 3:11, Luke 3:16, Acts 2:3, 4, 7:30, Rom 12:11, 1 Thess 5:19, Rev 4:5, 7, 8:5, 14:10, 18, 15:2, 19:20, 20:9, 10)
- **Meat** - was a symbol of the sacrifice of Messiah (John 6:51-56)
- **Grain** was a symbol, again, of the sacrificed Messiah (John 6:47-51, 58)

Comment: +1. Interesting that all the ingredients were relatively costly. I'd definitely like to dive more into the symbolism.